# Using sed replace with regex and variables containing numbers

Tags: sed

I'm having issues figuring out the syntax of a sed line. I use regex, so I went with double quotes around the whole thing. However, the windows path I'm replacing with has a number in it.

```
windowsPath="\\\\This\\path\\is\\the\\best\\1"
sed -i "s,^bestPath=.*,bestPath=${windowsPath}," pathfile
```

This gives me:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 126: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
```

I attempted leaving the variable out of the quotes to avoid interpretation, but then I got this:

Code:

```
windowsPath="\\\\This\\path\\is\\the\\best\\1"
sed -i "s,^bestPath=.*,bestPath="${windowsPath}"," pathfile
```

Result:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 42: unterminated `s' command
```

Any sed masters with ideas on what's going on here? I'm working in bash on RHEL 6

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What system are you on? In Bash, `windowsPath` gets stored as `\Thispathisthebest1` – all the single backslashes are gone because they don't mean anything. Then, the substitution string doesn't contain `\1` anywhere (and wouldn't even if the slashes were preserved); I don't see how you can get an invalid reference.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I've updated the question. There was supposed to be a '\' before the 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the windowsPath assignment, use single-quotes (') instead of double-quotes (").

```
#!/bin/bash

windowsPath='\\\\This\\path\\is\\the\\best\\1'
sed -e "s,^bestPath=.*,bestPath=${windowsPath}," pathfile

exit $?
```

Output is

```
bestPath=\\This\path\is\the\best\1
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This works perfectly. Since I don't control the variable assignment in the actual application, I just doubled the escapes to do the same thing. `"\\\\\\\\This\\\\path\\\\is\\\\the\\\\best\\\\1"` Ugly, but works. Thanks for pointing me to the fact that it was an escapes issue.